# Hide mailchimp popup on wordpess for desktop visitors

Tags: css, wordpress, mailchimp

Can find plenty of info on how to hide mailchimp on a mobile but looking to do the opposite. Have tried adding the code below to the css but doesn't work.

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #modalContent { 
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

Suspect I'm using the wrong class?

Answer (score 0):

OK think I've sussed this out, unless anyone want to correct me? The class is as below

`@media( min-width: 500px ) { #PopupSignupForm_0 { display: none !important;     visibility: hidden !important; } }`

Am I right?!

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try JavaScript for it you will able to detect Mobile, tablet and desktop devices separately.

```
function detectMob() {
      const toMatch = [
      /Android/i,
      /webOS/i,
      /iPhone/i,
      /iPad/i,
      /iPod/i,
      /BlackBerry/i,
      /Windows Phone/i
      ];

      return toMatch.some((toMatchItem) => {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(toMatchItem);
      });
    }

    function detectTab()
    {
      var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      return isTablet = /(ipad|tablet|(android(?!.*mobile))|(windows(?!.*phone)(.*touch))|kindle|playbook|silk|(puffin(?!.*(IP|AP|WP))))/.test(userAgent);
    }

    if(detectTab() == true)
    {
      console.log('tab');

    }
    else if(detectMob() == true)
    {
      console.log('mob');
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('desktop');
    }
```